# Running text marquee using jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

I'm trying to use jquery animate to do marquee running text on my html. Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scroll').animate({
    right: $(document).width() // animates right value from the original -200px(from css) to the documents width(ie if elements right value = the document width, then element is off screen)
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  right: -200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">This text be scrollin'!</div>
```

Here is the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/y9hvr9fa/

The problem is, it just run for one time only. May I know how to make it to run in endless loop?

Comment: I want to use animate from jquery... those answers is using css to do marquee

Comment: Please help... I'm not using css animate because my device not support. I just wan to use jquery animate...